# Help me find this Lasker Chess quote

Tags: lasker

I remember a few things from his saying - that he can produce a class A player out of an amateur in a span of so and so hours. I remember reading something along these lines, and I guess it's Lasker's quote, but my memory seems to fail me.

Answer (score 4):

Chapter "Final Reflections on Education in Chess"

page 373 in this pdf file:[Lasker's Manual of Chess](http://www.simardartizanfarm.ca/pdf/-_Lasker_s_Manual_of_Chess.pdf)